# How can I prevent syntastic from showing warning when file ignored?

Tags: vim, eslint, syntastic

I ignore some javascript files because it obviously can't follow javascript coding rule (yeoman generator). Off course, if I turned it on, syntastic will be mad at me. So, I ignore every files on templates directory. But, syntastic
keep warns me. How can I turn off the warning on those ignored files?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add all those files to:

```
let g:syntastic_ignore_files = ['\m^/temlates/', '\m\c\.h$']
```

Every entry in this Array is a RegExp so ignoring yeoman files should be easy to accomplish.

This information is available inside Syntastic help. I encourage you to explore all the options!

```
:help syntastic
```